# LocalDateTime Not Updating Within Program

Tags: java, datetime, time, formatter

I am using `LocalDateTime` and a `DateTimeFormatter` to use in my program like so

```
DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH-mm-ss");
LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now();
```

I need to get the seconds for some screenshots in my program 
but as i use them i only get one timestamp

Here is the rest of my code

```
// SCREENSHOT
    JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
    WebElement header = driver.findElement(By.xpath(
            "(.//*[normalize-space(text()) and normalize-space(.)='Button1'])[1]/following::nav[1]"));
    js.executeScript("arguments[0].setAttribute('style', 'position: static !important;')", header);
    Screenshot screenshot1 = new AShot()
            .shootingStrategy(ShootingStrategies.viewportPasting(ShootingStrategies.scaling(2f), 1000))
            .takeScreenshot(driver);
    Thread.sleep(5000);
    ImageIO.write(screenshot1.getImage(), "PNG", new File(Constants.ROUTE
            + "/asd/Asd/web/" + capName + now.format(dtf) + ".png"));
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    // // SCREENSHOT
```

This is the first capture i take.
I concatenate with `now.format(dtf)`
Then when i take a second capture

```
// SCREENSHOT
    JavascriptExecutor js1 = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
    WebElement header1 = driver.findElement(By.xpath(
            "(.//*[normalize-space(text()) and normalize-space(.)='Button2'])[1]/following::nav[1]"));
    js.executeScript("arguments[0].setAttribute('style', 'position: static !important;')", header1);
    Screenshot screenshot2 = new AShot()
            .shootingStrategy(ShootingStrategies.viewportPasting(ShootingStrategies.scaling(2f), 1000))
            .takeScreenshot(driver);
    Thread.sleep(5000);
    ImageIO.write(screenshot2.getImage(), "PNG", new File(Constants.ROUTE
            + "/asd/Asd/web/" + capName + now.format(dtf) + ".png"));
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    // // SCREENSHOT
```

It prints out the same timestamp and my program overwrites the capture

Comment: And do you call LocalDateTime.now() each time ?

Comment: I tried to call it before each capture but i get the same results

Answer (score 3):

`LocalDateTime` is a type used to represent a date and time (without timezones). `LocalDateTime.now()` return the `LocalDateTime` that represent the current date and time. What you are doing right now, is calling `LocalDateTime.now()` and expecting the `LocalDateTime` you get to update itself, instead you should do `LocalDateTime.now()` everytime you need the current date and time.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to take the time at two differents moments, then you should really use 2 variables (or constants) :

```
LocalDateTime now1 = LocalDateTime.now(); // First timestamp
// do some display of now1.format(dtf)
...
LocalDateTime now2 = LocalDateTime.now(); // Second timestamp
// do some display of now2.format(dtf)
```